# How can I test create an instance of a VisualForce Controller Extension for testing?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension, apex, standardcontroller

Typical of custom controller extensions, my extension has a signature

```
public MyVFCtrlExt (ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
```

I'm currently trying to figure out how to write unit tests for the methods in the controller class.

To do this, I want to create an instance of MyVFCtrlExt, so I can write tests like this:

```
@isTest private static void testMyMethod()
{
     // GIVEN
         /* Some setup code */

     ApexPages.StandardController standardController = null; // TODO;
     MyVFCtrlExt myVFCtrlExt = new MyVFCtrlExt(standardController);

     // WHEN
     System.runAs(TEST_RUN_USER)
     {
        Test.startTest();
        {
            myVFCtrlExt.myMethod();
        }
        Test.stopTest(); 
     }

     // THEN
         /* Assert some things. */

}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to  create an instance of the ApexPages.StandardController, which is a prerequisite to creating the controller extension.

How can/should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to first provide object reference and then use that as a constructor, please see below example:

```
ex=TestDataFactory.createexam(tform.Id,extaker.id,NEWx);
ex.Name='Chemistry';
ex.Test_Form__r=tform;
ex.Test_Form__r.Passing_Score__c=tform.Passing_Score__c;
insert ex

// call the constructor
Examcontroller  controller = new Examcontroller (new ApexPages.StandardController(ex));
```

Comment: This looks good!  Will try when I get back to work tomorrow.  Thanks.  :-)